# Vimscript imap ctrl bug

Tags: vim

I am new to vimscrip. I am experimenting with some code in .vimrc to customize my vim text editor.

Here is my entire code:

```
map m dd
vmap a Gy
imap <c-i> #include
iabbrev LOL Mark was here
autocmd VimEnter * echo "Welcome to vim :)"

if strftime("%H") < 12
    set background=light
else
    set background=dark
endif
```

Everything works perfectly except for the `imap <c-i> #include`.

If I type `CTRL+i` in insert mode, it writes `#include` like it should.

However, if I push `TAB`, it also writes `#include` when I am in insert mode.

I do not understand why this happens. Advice anyone? Thank you

Comment: `<Tab>` and `<C-i>` are indistinguishable from each other. You need to choose another shortcut.

Comment: Is `<c-i>` specifically indistinguishable from `<Tab>` or can I do `<c-m>` (as int `ctrl+m`) for instance?

Comment: `<C-m>` is indistinguishable from `<CR>`. You should try `<leader>` mappings: `:help mapleader`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's not a bug, it's an unfortunate design limitation.**

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.